# Use scala.Either from Java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop, either

I'm using a scala library from java, specifically a function that returns `Either[A, B]`. In my java code I can do:

```
scalaFunction.callMethod(new Function<Either<A, B>>() {
   public byte[] apply(Either<A, B> result) {
      B right = result.right().???
   }
}
```

`result.right()` returns a `RightProjection`, but I can't import that in Java (using IntelliJ). Is there a proper way to deal with Either objects in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this, but according to the ScalaDoc for [`RightProjection`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/util/Either%24%24RightProjection.html), you should be able to call `get()`. Note that this throws an exception if `result` is not a `Right`.

In order to work with Scala classes in an IDE, the IDE needs to know about them. Thus you need to add `scala-library.jar` into the build path specified in your IDE. For the IDE (and the Java compiler and runtime), Scala is just a regular library that is a dependency of all libraries and programs written in Scala.

Comment: The problem is I can't even import RightProjection from Java. So doing result.right().get() won't compile. I guess RightProjection is nested within the Either companion object in the source file, so it's hidden from the Java perspective?

Comment: Your IDE should be able to show you the return type of `right()`, use this for importing. I guess it's `scala.util.Either$RightProjection` or `scala.util.Either$RightProjection$`.

Comment: Did you include the Scala JAR file in your IDE? If not, do so, then it should be working. You need `scala-library.jar`, it contains the byte code for the relevant classes.

Comment: Yep, look's like that fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`RightProjection` and `LeftProjection` are nested classes defined within `object Either` (not an inner class of `class Either`). You'll have to track down the encoding of Scala objects to JVM classes. I think it's the object name with a `$` appended and some other stuff... Then the JVM-level `RightProjection` class will be one whose name combines the object's class name and a `$` (another one, I think) and `RightProjection`.

Or something like that. I've never had to dig this deep.

The stock `javap` tool can help you track down this information.